# Clamping camera forward and backward vector in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

My perspective camera is rotated on the x axis. I've implemented a zoom with the scroll wheel and it works great.

I'm trying to limit the zoom, however. My solution right now is to take the relative scale of the `transform.forward` y and z components and clamp the y and z position of the camera by using `Mathf.Clamp` and multiplying the `minZoom` and `maxZoom` floats by the corresponding `transform.forward` component. It works well, except it limits the y axis, so when I translate around I can't go below a given y due to my clamp with is ideally meant to affect the zoom only.

Is there a way to clamp the forward and backward movement of the camera? I've been looking everywhere but can't find a thing.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here's the relevant code (my clamping occurs in LateUpdate):

```
public class ClickManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float dragSpeed = 2;
    public float minZoom = 0.5f;
    public float maxZoom = 5.0f;

    private Vector3 dragOrigin;

    private float lerpPercentBack = 0; // value between 0 and 1 representing percentage of lerp
    private float lerpPercentForward = 0;
    private bool isLerpingBack = false;
    private bool isLerpingForward = false;



    void Update()
    {
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            return;
        }

        if (scroll > 0)
        {
            isLerpingForward = true;
            lerpPercentForward = 0;
        }
        if (scroll < 0)
        {
            isLerpingBack = true;
            lerpPercentBack = 0;
        }



        if (isLerpingBack)
        {
            scrollLerperBack();
            lerpPercentBack += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentBack >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentBack = 0;
                isLerpingBack = false;
            }
        }


        if (isLerpingForward)
        {

            scrollLerperForward();
            lerpPercentForward += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentForward >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentForward = 0;
                isLerpingForward = false;
            }
        }

        //Debug.Log(lerpPercent);

        /*if (!Input.GetMouseButton(1)) return;

        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - dragOrigin);
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, pos.y * dragSpeed, 0);

        transform.Translate(move, Space.World);

        Debug.Log(scroll);*/


    }


    void scrollLerperBack()
    {
        transform.position -= Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, Vector3.zero, lerpPercentBack);
    }


    void scrollLerperForward()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, Vector3.zero, lerpPercentForward);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;

        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, minZoom * transform.forward.y,
            maxZoom * transform.forward.y);
        pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, minZoom * transform.forward.z, 
            maxZoom * transform.forward.z);
        transform.localPosition = pos;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of explaining your code in paragraphs, its better to post it with question. Programming languages are easy to understand rather than English :)

Comment: Sure, I'll add the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float dragSpeed = 2;
    public float minZoom = 0.5f;
    public float maxZoom = 5.0f;

    private Vector3 dragOrigin;

    private float lerpPercentBack = 0; 
    private float lerpPercentForward = 0;
    private bool isLerpingBack = false;
    private bool isLerpingForward = false;

    Vector3 forwardPos;
    Vector3 backwardPos;
    void Start()
    {
        forwardPos = transform.position ;
        forwardPos.z += maxZoom;

        backwardPos = transform.position ;
        backwardPos.z += minZoom;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            return;
        }

        if (scroll > 0)
        {
            isLerpingForward = true;
            lerpPercentForward = 0;
        }
        if (scroll < 0)
        {
            isLerpingBack = true;
            lerpPercentBack = 0;
        }



        if (isLerpingBack)
        {
            scrollLerperBack();
            lerpPercentBack += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentBack >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentBack = 0;
                isLerpingBack = false;
            }
        }


        if (isLerpingForward)
        {

            scrollLerperForward();
            lerpPercentForward += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentForward >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentForward = 0;
                isLerpingForward = false;
            }
        }
    }


    void scrollLerperBack()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, backwardPos, Time.deltaTime * dragSpeed );
    }


    void scrollLerperForward()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, forwardPos, Time.deltaTime * dragSpeed);
    }


}
```

Comment: My camera is rotated on the x axis however, if I moved only on the z axis the camera would move up instead of back. The transform.forward vector is (0,0.6,0.8)

Comment: Didn't you say that you want to clamp forward and backward moment? So when it is rotated around x axis by 90 for example, it will be facing downward. So scrolling back means translating it upward in world.

Comment: Its rotated by something like -30 degrees, so I mean backwards relative to where the camera is facing. Sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: Rotating transform also rotates forward. So its always gonna be back and forth no matter what rotation is. Just use the code I updated in answer and test it. It works perfect.

Comment: The thing is, when I zoom to the max of the camera's z position, y is unbounded so it continues to scroll on the y-axis

Comment: I ended up deciding to use FOV due to its simplicity, thanks for all the help though +1